# Security Concerns Using EmailJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Should I have any concerns with security when using [EmailJS](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs)?

I feel as though entering all the email account information in plaintext in my app.js file is a huge security risk. Can't one just navigate through my source code to find my AppJS pull up code on that and see my email username and password clear as day?

Answer (score 1):

app.js is only run server side. Regular outside users should not be able to read it.

Anyone that can access the private files on your server can read it.

If someone is in your server, you have bigger problems than them sending emails.

Comment: So when running a MeanJS application, the app.js file in the root of the application is only run server side?

Comment: Yes. In the normal setup when you run `node app.js` that is all server side.  It just happens to open and port and take requests.

Comment: So if I create my `var email = require('emailjs')` in my root app.js along with the `email.server.connect({})` method, then how can I reference it in my public angularApp.js file so I can call `send` on it?

Comment: You would only use` server.send(message, function(err, message) { console.log(err || message); });` from the app.js side (server side).    you would need to add a method that your angular app calls , then use that to call the server.send    here is an example that uses "nodemailer" instead of "emailJS" but the concept is similar https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/send-e-mail-node-js/